# Using bootstrap table with input fields

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using [bootstrap table](https://bootstrap-table.com/).

My table contains cells that contains input fields.

When the user changes the value of an input field I need to do the following in order to keep the table sorted.

1. "Ask" the table if the input field that was just changed belongs to the column that the table is sorted by.
2. If the answer to question number 1 is true, I need to "tell" the table to sort the rows.

My questions are:

- Dows the logic above feels correct?
- How do I (what is the API call I should use) in order to answer #1
- How to I call the "re-sort rows"  API of the table?

Code snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>sorted table</title>
</head>
<body>

<span>A Bootstrap table</span>

<table id="my_table_1" data-toggle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-sortable="true">A</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">B</th>
        <th data-sortable="true">C</th>
        <th data-sortable="false">D</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="112">A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="356" selected>C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2018-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1" selected>A</option>
                <option val="2">B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-22"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>56</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-08-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td><select>
                <option val="1">A</option>
                <option val="2" selected>B</option>
                <option val="3">C</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="date" value="2014-07-23"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.15.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          console.log('ready');
          $('#my_table_1').find('input[type="date"]').change(function() {
            console.log('Table 1.Date was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column C.If so - call the table sort.');
          });
          $('#my_table_1').find('select').change(function() {
            console.log('Table 1.Selection was changed. Need to check if table is sorted by column B.If so - call the table sort.');
          });
         });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same as [#987](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/987), you need to call `updateRow` to save the change to the table `data`: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/wenzhixin/737.

Comment: In #987 the column "Selling" is not sortable. In my case the columns that contains input fields are sortable so I need to trigger the table sort after the input field value is changed. Will the call to `updateRow` will do that?

Comment: Question. In example #987 the table is rendered based on json data. In my case the table is rendered on the server side. How can I adopt the provided solution to my model? (I am asking since the function `selectFormatter` gets the select markup as  the `value` argument and not the selected value as in your example)

Comment: If you are using server-side pagination, I think you need to post data to the server.

Comment: I do not use server side pagination. The table contains 10 to 50 records only. When the user changes the value of input field the change is propagated to the server via XHR. When the XHR call is done - I would like the table to be sorted based on the user changes. Any directions?

Comment: is it possible to use `<input type="number">` instead of `<option>`?